# How to clear field when submitting form

Tags: html

I'm using `<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>`
To submit the form without without redirecting the tab, but the "Type something..." field is not
is not displayed again when submitted.
The submit button is `<button class="login100-form-btn"> submit </button>`
And I already tried with `<button class="login100-form-btn" type="reset"> submit </button>`
What clears the field but does not submit the form
I also got the idea to put a link when pressed to send.
The page reloads the field comes back empty but the form is not submitted, doing so
`<a href="http://www.pseudo.link"><button class="login100-form-btn">submit</button></a>`
Also tried using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://www.pseudo.link">`
what made the page at a given second refresh all the time

```html
<div class="limiter">
  <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');">
    <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-54">
      <iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
      <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/.../formResponse" target="votar">
        <span class="login100-form-title p-b-49">Make a comment.</span>
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate="Username is reauired">
          <input class="input100" type="text" name="entry.???" placeholder="Type something...">
        </div>
        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
          <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
            <button class="login100-form-btn">submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you think wrapping a button in a ink would improve things? 
Why not use Ajax if you do not want to reload the tab, and then update the page with the changes

Comment: You seem to be bouncing back and forth between expected behaviors.  You added this weird `<iframe>` workaround to prevent the page from responding to the form submit, but are now trying to get the page to respond to the form submit (by reloading the empty form).  It sounds like you're trying to avoid using JavaScript, which is exactly the tool you want to use to customize your page's behavior.

Comment: ajax is js right?
I wanted to leave it only in html and css, but I'll try some changes here on localhost.
is that without the `iframe`, the page redirects to the google form that is inside the `action="".` And I just wanted to keep it on my page, sending the data to google

Comment: @Cmistry: If the form is being posted to another server then you *may* run into CORS issues if you use AJAX.  It depends on whether the target server allows CORS requests.  You *can* still keep the existing `<iframe>` workaround and not use AJAX.  But, to clear the fields, you'll still need to use JavaScript to add a custom submit handler to the form, just don't prevent the default form action in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added to the `<form>` a `onsubmit='this.submit();this.reset();return false;'`

```html
<div class="limiter">
  <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');">
    <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-54">
      <iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
      <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/.../formResponse" target="votar" onsubmit='this.submit();this.reset();return false;'>
        <span class="login100-form-title p-b-49">Make a comment.</span>
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate="Username is reauired">
          <input class="input100" type="text" name="entry.???" placeholder="Type something...">
        </div>
        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
          <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
            <button class="login100-form-btn">submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `script.js` file or javascript code into your file where you have to write code to submit the form.
And there write submit function with `.reset()` property and don't prevent the default form action in that code